# Search tool used by Kubuntu 19.10 "application dashboard" widget, how can I alter search?

Tags: kubuntu, search, plasma, widgets

The search results seem a bit strange.  There aren't many options when you right click on the widget icon.  What search program is this using and how can I alter it to get better search results?

examples of strange behaviour I'd like to correct/alter:

1. When I type "s" the search comes up with applications with names starting with "s" but also some that don't.  It also comes up with a number files many or which have names that don't even start with "s".  Why?  How can I change that?
2. If I type "se"  no applications show up but files do (some not starting with "se".)
3. If I type "set" application starting with "set" show up.  Why didn't they show up when typing just "se"?

Answer (score 0):

Caution: this is going to be a somewhat speculative and far from complete answer!

Posted from a VM running Kubuntu 19.10 (minimal install option) with the [kubuntu-backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=eoan) enabled.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.17.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.65.0
Qt Version: 5.12.4
Kernel Version: 5.3.0-24-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

---

The title of the question refers to the *application dashboard*. According to [kde.org's announcement page](https://kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.4.0.php),

> Plasma 5.4 brings an entirely new fullscreen launcher Application
>   Dashboard in kdeplasma-addons: Featuring all features of Application
>   Menu it includes sophisticated scaling to screen size and full spatial
>   keyboard navigation. The new launcher allows you to easily and quickly
>   find applications, as well as recently used or favorited documents and
>   contacts based on your previous activity.

A small video from 2015 illustrating the application dashboard is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yE9fV8II6eI).

(There are [other launchers available](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff) as part of the default installation.)

---

Re.

> The search results seem a bit strange.  There aren't many options when you right click on the widget icon.  What search program is this using and how can I alter it to get better search results?

**Right-clicking on the launcher icon**:

[image: Right-clicking on the dashboard icon]

This context menu doesn't provide any option for altering how the search box functions.

However, some information can be gleaned from [the kickoff page](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff)

> you can simply enter a search term. The search field has focus when opening the menu, so you can simply start typing. The search will not only match against applications names, but also against their description. So if you need a browser, but don't know the name of the installed browsers, simply type "browser" in the search field. This should result in a list of all available browsers.

Re.

> When I type "s" the search comes up with applications with names starting with "s" but also some that don't.  It also comes up with a number files many or which have names that don't even start with "s".  Why?  How can I change that?

- based on the bit I quoted from the kickoff page, *both* the application's name and its description are taken into account. Plus, it appears that a result is shown if what is typed matches *anywhere*, not just the first letter, in the name or the description.

**Even internal strings are matched**

[image: even internal strings are matched]

A couple of points about *descriptions*:

- Applications with .desktop files have their *Comments* searched. For example, I installed `meld` and it has "Compare and merge your files", so typing *merg* picks up `meld` on *my* system.
- Then there are also items specific to KDE Plasma such as those components, aka modules, found in *System Settings*. You can get an idea of (many of) those and their descriptions by running `kcmshell5 --list` in your terminal.

> 2. If I type "se"  no applications show up but files do (some not starting with "se".)

No applications showing up when "se" is typed even though just "s" itself returns results is probably a bug and could be reported at [KDE Bugtracking System](https://bugs.kde.org/).

Files showing up even though their names don't start with "se" has been dealt with above. An additional wrinkle is *baloo*. If a user chooses to index the *contents* of files (*System Settings > Search*), files containing "se" as part of their content will be picked up.

> 3. If I type "set" application starting with "set" show up.  Why didn't they show up when typing just "se"?

It's already mentioned that no results are returned for applications when searching just for "se".

---

As for

> how can I alter it to get better search results?

Other than typing longer strings, I can't think of ways a user can get better search results. (It's possible that the system trains itself to recognize a user's intentions depending on how often a particular file or application is launched. I use `krunner` rather than the dashboard, and when I type just "a", the first item listed is *abanks.odt*, a file I open several times a day.)

The other option is to get involved:

> More generally, have a look at https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved and find out more ways to help be part of a project that really matters. Each contributor makes a huge difference in KDE; you are not a number or a cog in a machine! You don’t have to already be a programmer, either. I wasn’t when I got started. Try it, you’ll like it! We don’t bite!

[Source](https://pointieststick.com/2019/12/22/this-week-in-kde-its-gonna-be-amaaaaaaaaaaazing/)

Comment: I learned a few things following up from the above. 1. It looks the search isn't using baloo because I delete the baloo search  data and the search continued to function even before the files had a chance to rebuild themselves.  Is that a valid assumption?  2. The *.desktop files some programs have, have an "Action" category that gets searched.  For example, every time I typed setting, Steam would appear ahead  of System Settings.  Removing "setting" from the steam.desktop file fixed that.

Comment: Another annoyance is that any search that matches a command line argument automatically comes up with a "run command_name" option.  I'd love to stop that from happening too.

Comment: Really, at least get a [KDE ID](https://identity.kde.org/) and then login to phabricator. Then, you can be part of the development process. For example, see https://phabricator.kde.org/T7913, https://phabricator.kde.org/T9041, https://phabricator.kde.org/T12192